# jquery unbind click

Tags: jquery

I'm going nuts just trying to unbind an onclick handler from the event in jQuery so I can bind it later on to another function.

I have isolated the code in a test page so there's nothing but the meat, just a button that calls a function and a script that **tries** to unbind it:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" 
                      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() { $("#btnNext").unbind('click'); });
        function hi() {window.alert("hi");}
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <input id="btnNext" type="button" value="Next" onclick="hi();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Anybody knows why the click event keeps calling the hi() function no matter what I said in the document.ready?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because you put it in the html attribute, it stays there. It was not bound with jQuery so jQuery is not tracking it's usage.

```
$("a").bind('click',hi);
$("a").unbind('click',hi);
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Events/bind

Comment: Do you mean anything set in a declarative mode cannot be unbind like this?

Comment: correct, you maybe be able to unbind it by $("#btnNext").attr('onclick','') ... but better to do all your binding with jQuery. It's much cleaner and less confusing. Easy to forget about the javascript you added in your attributes. ;)

Comment: Nice one, now I understand why it didn't work. I'll do the binding as you say. Thanks!

Comment: np ;) also noticed you have jQuery added twice, ya just need the .min version.

Answer (score 9):

Just for the record, you can use the `removeAttr` jQuery function to remove the initially specified `onclick` attribute.

```
$('#btnNext').removeAttr("onclick");
```

Also, in response to Chad, I agree that it is generally better to do all your binding with jQuery, but I'm in a situation (using ASP.NET MVC) that requires individual links to have some model parameters in their click event handlers. It would be more convoluted IMO to try to wire  up these event handlers via jQuery.

Comment: this doesn't work in IE (of course). Anyone know a way to unbind "onclick" events in IE?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get removeAttr to work, but this does:

```
$("#btnNext").click(function(){ return false; });
```

I was wanting to remove the ASP.NET-supplied onclicks (just for SelectedNodeChanged) in my TreeView, so I could handle the event on the client. Of course, my click function included more than "return false".

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have

```
$(elem).on("click", function() { ... });
```

you don't even need to bind it if you want to unbind it later. To do so can just do:

```
$(elem).unbind();
```

and that will remove the handlers regardless of type. If you want to be more specific, you can always pass an event type like "click".